# Creat Cron Job to Reapply Permissions on QNAP NAS

Tags: linux, cron, qnap

I have a QNAP NAS running Google Drive sync so that my QNAP, Computers and Google Drive are all in Sync.

When I create a file on my work computer and get home to the QNAP I get an access denied error on the file I created at work.

If I view the permissions I can see they are set incorrectly. From the QNAP web manager I simply right click the folder containing my files and set permissions to "Reapply and apply to subfolders/files".

How would one go about doing the above via a cron job that runs say every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem myself and also made a cron job for it.

start of with making a script in a easy to find place.
I used "/share/MD0_DATA/" because all the shares live here.

Create a file like perms.sh and add the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /share/MD0_DATA/(folder you want to apply this)
chmod -R 775 *
chown -R nobody:nogroup *
```

I used the nobody:nogroup just for example you can use any user and group you want.

Now you need to add this script to crontab.
To see whats in your crontab use:

```
crontab -l
```

to edit the crontab use:

```
crontab -e
```

This editor works like vi if you don't like vi and want to access the file directly edit:

```
/etc/config/crontab
```

Add this line to your crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /share/MD0_DATA/perms.sh
```

The 5 represents a 5 minute interval.
Then you need to let crontab know about the new commands:

```
crontab /etc/config/crontab
```

I hope this helped you.